# Facing issue to Show Profile Picture of facebook using PHP sdk v.5

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter

**My code**

```
try {
  $response = $fb->get('/me?fields=id,name,gender,email,picture', $accessToken);
            } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
              echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
              exit;
            } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
              echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
              exit;
            }

            $user = $response->getGraphUser();

            echo 'Name:'.$user['name']."</br>";
            echo 'gender:'.$user['gender']."</br>";
            echo 'picture:'.$user['picture']."</br>";
            echo 'email:'.$user['email']."</br>";
```

**My output**

> Name:Siddhu Siddhartha Roy  gender:male 
>   picture:{"is_silhouette":false,"url":"https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/p50x50/12295307_890342681035161_8265283125930543183_n.jpg?
>   oh=f8198fc14435078e584749f2d55dcd8e&oe=5833FDCD"} 
>   email:siddhu.08pc1a0413@gmail.com

**My Problem**

I'm unable to show profile picture.. when I goto URL

> https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/p50x50/12295307_890342681035161_8265283125930543183_n.jpg

it shows that **Content not found**

Comment: I have no problem using file_put_contents to download the pic to my server.

Comment: Can you give me an example @Eric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple: You're getting the data in JSON format. So decode the result.

```
$json = json_decode($user['picture'], true);
        echo $json['url'];
```